# Site doesn't scroll smoothly (HTML + CSS)

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm creating a site using HTML and CSS for a school project (there's no JS involved).

I use a Smooth Scrolling addon on Google Chrome, but the page **doesn't scroll smoothly** like every other page on the Internet does. Instead, it scrolls in blocky chunks down the page.

JSFiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/L9wLm0qf/1/)

```
<div id="header" class="shadow2">
<div id="header-container">
<a href="index.html">
<div id="logo"></div>
</a>
```

*(the first few lines of code just for the JSFiddle link)*

Interestingly, the **preview in JSFiddle** scrolls smoothly :/

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't understand your question? Are you talking about the normal scrolling of the browser not being smooth?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Chrome, and it scrolls just fine.

Scrolling is controlled by your mouse settings, so maybe something changed with your scroll wheel?